# This pull request requires an explicit override to bypass policies that aren't currently passing

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-branch, pull-request

My company is using VSTS with git. I'm trying to complete a pull request to update translation strings.  In our develop branch we have Branch policies set to require 2 approvals before a pull request can be completed.

Normally for the translation string pull requests I've been bypassing the two approval branch policy by temporarily making the MyRepository Administrators group Exempt from policy enforcement and then Clearing the explicit permissions on the develop branch immediately after completing the pull request for the translation strings.

Starting about last week this is no longer working.  When I try to complete the pull request I see a message that says: "This pull request requires an explicit override to bypass policies that aren't currently passing."

Any idea what's changed?  I don't see any way to do an explicit override, does anyone know how to do this?  I haven't found anything useful searching the web.

Here's the develop branch's security settings:
[image: Screenshot of develop branch security]

Here's the develop branch's Policies:
[image]

Here's what I see when I try to complete a pull request after approving it:

[image]

Here's the error message:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Why would you have that policy if you are just going to bypass it?

Comment: I only bypass the policy for translation strings, not for changes to C#, JavaScript, etc.  I imagine the policy is probably enforced for 95% of our pull requests.

Comment: Why dont you exclude the translation strings from the rule for approval? You can set a negative path.

Comment: @Eric, can you give your detail steps or may be some screenshots for your settings? And what's the PR was when you got the message, is it also another branch merge into develop branch?

Comment: @MrHinsh It looks like I can set specific reviewers for specific paths within a branch, but the minimum number of approvers is set at the branch level.

Comment: @Marina-MSFT I've added some screenshots.

Comment: @Eric, based on your setting, I can run it successfully: **Exempt from policy enforcement** for develop branch project administrators -> complete pull request by **override branch policies and enable merge** -> clear explicit permissions in the first step -> create pull create -> set exempt policy as the first step -> complete pull request by bypass (**override branch policies and enable merge**) -> successful.

Comment: @Marina-MSFT It sounds like your comment is an answer to my question, but I'm not able to figure out how to do it.  Where do I "complete pull request by override branch policies and enable merge?"  Keep in mind that I'm not the person creating the pull request, just trying to approve and completed it.  I've added some more screenshots.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This also used for the situation that PR is not created by you, and you are member of project administrators. Below is steps:

1. In https://account.visualstudio.com/projectname/_admin/_versioncontrol, select the **repo** and **branch** you want to use bypass police ->  select **Project Administrators** -> set **Exempt from policy enforcement** allow -> save changes.
   [image]
2. In the pull request, complete pull request by selecting **Override branch policies and enable merge** -> Override & Complete.
   [image]
3. Clear explicit permissions and save changes.
   [image]
4. For later pull request, if need bypass policy, you can set same as above steps.

Your screen shot of complete pull request seems approved at least by 2 reviewers since it not shows the notice message.

Comment: I've successfully completed a couple pull requests this way, but now I've hit one that doesn't have the Override branch policies and enable merge checkbox.  Any idea what's up with that?

Comment: Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyP1e.png) of what I'm talking about

Comment: It seems like I have to refresh the pull request in my browser window after having set the develop branch as Exempt from policy enforcement in order to get the Override branch policies and enable merge checkbox to appear.

Comment: For Azure DevOps services, this is now known as "Bypass policies when completing pull requests" and "Bypass policies when pushing" See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#bypass-branch-policies for details

Comment: Tried the solution, unfortunately it didn't work in Azure DevOps. At the end, I set up my permissions to allow 'Bypass policies when pushing', then force the push to the branch.